# Using Facebook Graph API + PHP SDK to get User's About data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Graph API and the PHP SDK, I know that I can get the user interests with

```
$facebook->api("/me/interests")
```

However, assuming that I have the permission to, how can I get the user's About data?

```
$facebook->api("/me/about")
//gives error:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Unknown path components: /about thrown in 
[...]/base_facebook.php on line 1028
```

How can I get the logged in user's Facebook About data? Thanks.

**EDIT:** Here's a picture of the app permissions, as well as the code used to request the permissions.

[image: The Permissions for My App]

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email, publish_stream, 
user_about_me, user_interests, user_education_history'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what 'about' information you want? You can specify individual fields but there is no overall about command to get all about information. Just go

```
$info = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,email,work');
```

You can get a full list of what you can request plus further commands from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Edit, if you are wanting the bio just add ',bio' to the fields

Comment: This feature is working weirdly. Sometimes it returns what I specify, sometimes it just returns the user ID. $facebook->api("/me?fields=bio") only returns the ID.

Comment: $facebook->api("/me?fields=bio") will return only id. You can use $facebook->api("/me"). Check my answer

Comment: Your answer seems to be suggesting to use /me?fields=bio.

Comment: You should be able to when I run /me?fields=bio I get a return from facebook with my bio. Have a mess around with the build in facebook graph api explorer. Remember the user may not have a bio set.

Comment: I should clarify that if you do not have permissions or are not sending the app information and access token correctly your only going to get basic information from /me?fields=

Comment: Right you SHOULD be able to just go $facebook->api('/me'); and get all this data given your permissions. So try going $value = $facebook->api('/me'); print_r($value); and see what is outputted, if you can see the output it should be a matter of going $value['bio'] to get it.  If that doesn't work try going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ from the drop down menu on the top right select your application. Then see what information it can get. Could be that the user doesn't have a bio, if they don't the field won't be returned.

Comment: I somehow got it to work now, exactly as you told me to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be :

```
$facebook->api("/me/bio") ;
```

EDIT:

Just Use this:

```
$facebook->api("/me") ;
```

You can get all user information from this . Just parse the array for what you required . It outputs all the user related information

Some attributes like users phone,address are specifically and intentionally not available via the API, for spam prevention reasons . Facebook does not allow them to take through api

Try with this :)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately: "...Unknown path components: /bio thrown in..."

Answer (score 0):

That kind of errors `Unknown path components: /xxx` usually occur when you are not properly logged in your `developer` account.

It may sound obvious, But I had similar problems until habituate to check/change accounts before work. {>_<}